# SVG not changing the direction in RTL languages

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on Project where i used svg star rating section. In ltr All project switch to RTL as i used Bootstrap 5 Css Framework expect This section. How Can i fix this issue in RTL.

Here is the Code:

```
<svg id="stars" style="display: none;" version="1.1">
  <symbol id="stars-empty-star" viewBox="0 0 102 18" fill="#F1E8CA">
    <path d="M9.5 14.25l-5.584 2.936 1.066-6.218L.465 6.564l6.243-.907L9.5 0l2.792 5.657 6.243.907-4.517 4.404 1.066 6.218" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="stars-full-star" viewBox="0 0 102 18" fill="#D3A81E">
    <path d="M9.5 14.25l-5.584 2.936 1.066-6.218L.465 6.564l6.243-.907L9.5 0l2.792 5.657 6.243.907-4.517 4.404 1.066 6.218" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="stars-half-star" viewBox="0 0 102 18" fill="#D3A81E">
    <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
    <path d="M9.5 14.25l-5.584 2.936 1.066-6.218L.465 6.564l6.243-.907L9.5 0l2.792" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- 0 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 0.5 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 1 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 1.5 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 2 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 2.5 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 3 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 3.5 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 4 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-empty-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 4.5 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" />
</svg>

<!-- 5 Rating -->
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="rating">
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
  <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" />
</svg>
```

I also have Codepen of it: Please check and suggest the solution in RTL

https://codepen.io/rebelchris/pen/dyXORMd

Comment: How about using `svg { transform: scale(-1,1); }` in the css?

Comment: It working now with your solution...Thanks:)

Comment: please read about the [<switch>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/switch) SVG element used to swich content depending on the browser's language settings